# How can I avoid that array_merge_recursive() tranform properties into arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm trying to [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge-recursive.php) two arrays.

```
  $arrayA = array(
    'properties' => array(
      'path' => array(
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'multiple' => array(
        'default' => true,
      ),
    )
  );

  $arrayB = array(
    'properties' => array(
      'path' => array(
        'default' => 'foo',
      ),
      'multiple' => array(
        'default' => false,
      ),
    )
  );

  $array = array_merge_recursive($arrayA,$arrayB);
  print_r($array);
```

Which gives

```
Array (
  [properties] => Array (
    [path] => Array (
      [default] => Array (
        [0] => 
        [1] => foo 
        ) 
      ) 
    [multiple] => Array ( 
      [default] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

As you can see, the *default* and *multiple* properties are merged into arrays since it exists in both arrays.

But I don't want them to be transformed into arrays, I want that the last value to override the previous one.

And of course they DO exists in both array, I cannot declare it only in the second one.

How could I achieve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does [`array_replace_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) do what you want? Or are there some elements that you *do* want to merge?

Comment: It does, thank you so much !